# Qweb custom header in odoo

Tags: python, pdf, odoo, qweb

I have now  qweb report in PDF. But if my reports (sale order, for example) have more than one page, the header is on EACH page.

Only one field is displayed on the first page header. Other fields are repeated on each page header.
How to put one field header only on the first page? /h3 tag/

Thanks
Here is my code:

```
<template id="payment_header">
        <div class="header">
            <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <div class="col-xs-3" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    <table>
                        <tr class="text-left">
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li>
                                    <span class="page"/>
                                </li>
                                <li>/</li>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="topage"/>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <span>SHOP:</span>
                            <span t-esc="warehouse"/>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="center">
                        **<h3 class="text-center">
                            <font color="white">Payment</font>
                        </h3>**
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right" style="margin-top:20px; font-size: 12px; border: 1px solid black;">
                    <span>Period</span>
                    <span t-esc="date_to" t-field-options="{'format': 'yyyy/MM/dd'}"/> ~
                    <span t-esc="date_from" t-field-options="{'format': 'yyyy/MM/dd'}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: where is the qweb template source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this free Odoo addon. It might help you.

https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/10.0/report_qweb_element_page_visibility/

In this Example addon, you can add some Javascript code to report XML.

**Here is the code example**

layouts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="minimal_layout" inherit_id="report.minimal_layout">
        <xpath expr="//t[@t-if='subst is True']" position="replace">
            <t t-if="subst is True">
                <script>
                    function subst() {
                        var vars = {};
                        var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&amp;');
                        for (var i in x) {
                            var z = x[i].split('=', 2);
                            vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
                        }
                        var x=['frompage', 'topage', 'page', 'webpage', 'section', 'subsection', 'subsubsection'];
                        for (var i in x) {
                            var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
                            for (var j=0; j&lt;y.length; ++j)
                                y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
                        }
                        var operations = {
                            'not-first-page': function (elt) {
                                elt.style.visibility = (vars.page === vars.frompage) ? "hidden" : "visible";
                            },
                            'not-last-page': function (elt) {
                                elt.style.visibility = (vars.page === vars.topage) ? "hidden" : "visible";
                            },
                            'first-page': function (elt) {
                                elt.style.visibility = (vars.page === vars.frompage) ? "visible" : "hidden";
                            },
                            'last-page': function (elt) {
                                elt.style.visibility = (vars.page === vars.topage) ? "visible" : "hidden";
                            },
                        };
                        for (var klass in operations) {
                            var y = document.getElementsByClassName(klass);
                            for (var j=0; j&lt;y.length; ++j)
                                operations[klass](y[j]);
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </t>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

And then add below code to __manifest__.py:

```
'data': [
    'views/layouts.xml',
],
```